# How to return an array in c using pthreads?

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, pthreads

I tried to write a program that a thread returns an array of numbers by passing a random vector to the thread and thread returns 2 times of the vector. 
The program is running fine put I'm not getting the expected output.
The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <omp.h>
void *myThreaddouble();

int i,sum[10],first[10]={10,20,30,40,50};

void *myThreaddouble()
{

int *sum[10];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  sum[i]= first[i] + first[i];
}    

   pthread_exit(sum[i]);
}

int main()
{

 double total = omp_get_wtime();

 printf("This is using PThread\n");

  pthread_t tid1;
  pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, myThreaddouble, NULL);
  printf("Double of the vector:-   \n");
  for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
  {
    printf(" %d\n",(int) sum[i]);
  }
  pthread_join(tid1, sum[i]);

  total = omp_get_wtime() - total;
  printf("%lf is time to add\n",total);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;

}
```

and the output is as follows:

```
This is using PThread
Double of the vector:-   
 0
 0
 0
 0
 0
0.000188 is time to add
```

Which is not the expected output, so can someone tell me what is the mistake in this code and how to return an array using pthread. In the i should be able to sum all the return values.

I used `gcc q.c -lpthread -lrt -fopenmp` command to compile this program.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: For one thing, you should join the worker thread before printing out.

Comment: @babon I did as you said, but I'm still getting the same output.

Comment: Note that the type of `myThreaddouble()` does not match the type that `pthread_create()` expects.  While you'll probably get away with it, it isn't a good idea.  Returning an `int` as if it was a `void *` is similarly dubious, at best.  And using `pthread_exit(sum[i]);` is accessing data out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go. I have taken liberty to comment out the time calculation part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <omp.h>
void *myThreaddouble();

int i,sum[10],first[10]={10,20,30,40,50};

void *myThreaddouble(void *a)
{

//int *sum[10];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  sum[i]= first[i] + first[i];
}    

   //pthread_exit(sum[i]);
   pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{

// double total = omp_get_wtime();

 printf("This is using PThread\n");

  pthread_t tid1;
  pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, myThreaddouble, NULL);
  printf("Double of the vector:-   \n");

  //pthread_join(tid1, sum[i]);
  pthread_join(tid1, NULL);

  for ( i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++ )
  {
    printf(" %d\n",(int) sum[i]);
  }
 // pthread_join(tid1, sum[i]);

  //total = omp_get_wtime() - total;
  //printf("%lf is time to add\n",total);
  printf("\n");

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: @RohitMulay It works but there a some places where you could improve.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is being caused because of the line `int *sum[10];` in this function:

```
void *myThreaddouble()
{

int *sum[10];
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
  sum[i]= first[i] + first[i];
}
```

You are creating a local variable `sum`, which will have preference over the global variable `sum`, since it is in a inner scope. Try removing it.

Comment: Tired but it's not working, I'm getting the same output.